# jQuery Event Handler for immediate changes in inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, event-handling, onchange

I'm looking for a (jQuery) Event Handler that is executing a function immediately after a `input[type="text"]` value changed. The `.change` jQuery event handler is executing the function after the `input[type="text"]` looses focus (which may be good for another situation).

`keypress` / `up` / `down` only work when the user types something into an input (not when I'm manipulating it dynamically).

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What type of input is it? type=text?  Which browser(s) do you plan to support?

Comment: Yep. input[type="text"] (It'd be even more awesome with type="range" etc but text is enough). And basically every modern browser (not IE6).

Comment: *when I'm manipulating it dynamically* what do you mean with that? When you change the value using `.val()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would modify the JQuery change event to fire even when you change it dynamically with the `val` function.  It really doesn't make sense to me why this is not the default behavior in JQuery.  Here is the code to do this:

```
//Store the old val function
$.fn.custom_oldVal = $.fn.val;

//Update the val function to fire the change event where appropriate:
$.fn.val = function(value) {
    if(value == null || value == undefined){
        return this.custom_oldVal();
    } else {
        //Only call onchange if the value has changed
        if(value == this.custom_oldVal()){
            return this;//Return this object for chain processing
        } else {
            return this.custom_oldVal(value).change();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need it to fire at other times, add those event listeners as well, following the procedure mentioned by jimbojw.

Comment: It's not default because it could create nasty dependency chains or even loops when something is changed. If you need this a lot, you're better off with something like Angular or Knockout.

Answer (score 11):

One thing that I do in cases like this is to bind the same handler to a bunch of events.

```
$('input').bind("change blur keyup mouseup", function() {
    $(this).css("color", "red"); // or whatever you want to happen
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Thanks. But this is really not what I'm looking for.